# Using Elmah with ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack, elmah

I'm trying to use Elmah with ServiceStack but am encountering the following problems:

- When I go to `/elmah.axd` on my site it returns a 404 rather than showing the Elmah logging page.
- Emails dont seem to be sending

Here is the code:

I have set the LogManager.LogFactory in the constructor of `AppHost`:

```
public AppHost() //Tell ServiceStack the name and where to find your web services
    : base("StarterTemplate ASP.NET Host", typeof(HomeService).Assembly)
{
    LogManager.LogFactory = new ElmahLogFactory(new NLogFactory());
}
```

In `web.config` I have the following sections declared:

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
        <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
        <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
        <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
        <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>


<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpHandlers>
        <add path="*" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" />
        <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
        <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
        <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
        <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
    </httpModules>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
        <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
        <add name="Elmah" path="elmah.axd" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
    <modules>
        <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
        <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
        <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>

<location path="elmah.axd">
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="ServiceStack.Factory" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</location>

<elmah>
    <security allowRemoteAccess="true" />
    <errorLog type="Elmah.XmlFileErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="~/App_Data/Elmah" />
    <errorMail from="elmaherror@domain.com" to="myemail@domain.com" async="false" smtpServer="192.168.0.5" smtpPort="25" userName="" password="" />
</elmah>
```

The SMTPServer and Emails are all configured correctly and I can see the error XML files in `App_Data/Elmah` so error's are being logged..

Comment: Does moving the Elmah elements in the <httpHandlers> and <handlers> sections above the ServiceStack elements fix it?

Comment: Hi @paaschpa - That did solve the problem for viewing the page, however, I still don't receive emails?

Comment: See http://rossipedia.com/blog/2013/03/elmah-emails-and-servicestack/